# Docker Toolbox Mac command line and Kitematics fails

Tags: macos, docker, docker-toolbox

I have installed the new *Docker Toolbox* application for the Mac using both the graphical installer (the official one) and `brew cask install`.

In both cases, the Virtual Machine is correctly created, but something seems to be wrong in the environment because when I try to execute `docker-machine` on the command line, it fails like this:

```
$ docker-machine env default
open /Users/adeynack/.docker/machine/machines/default/ca.pem: no such file or directory
```

When I try `Kitematics`, it fails like this:

[image: Kitematics failing]

I tried `Delete VM and retry setup`, without success. Any insight or idea is welcome here.

EDIT: I am already using the test build 5.0.3 of VirtualBox.

Comment: In the meantime, switched to the native OS X implementation (BETA at the moment).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may have been caused by an issue with `Virtualbox`. The issue has been fixed with the latest testbuild for virtualbox here: [Virtualbox Test build](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Testbuilds).

You have to uninstall your current version of Virtual Box and install the test build.

**Edit**

You may need to create a new docker machine.

1. Create a new docker machine: 

   `docker-machine create --driver virtualbox dev`
2. Next, start the dev environment: 

   `docker-machine env dev`
3. Set up the environment for the dev machine: 

   `eval "$(docker-machine env dev)"`

Comment: I should have specified that I am already on VBox 5.0.3 (test build). Good lead, but already checked that possibility.

Comment: So, in short, the machine that is created by default does not work correctly. You need to delete it and create a new one manually (as gnerkus suggests in his post).

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
docker-machine regenerate-certs default
docker-machine restart default
```

Comment: Makes sense, since it seems to be some certificate (I guess that's what those ".cem" files are?) that are missing. Thanks for the solution!